# How to make custom cell width adjustable as per tableview frame

Tags: uitableview, custom-cell

I am using custom cell containing labels and images in tableview.On Button action am   shrinking the tableview frame but the custom cell width isn't shrinking accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For that perticular Cell do like this,

```
UIView *contentView = cell.contentView;
contentView.frame = tableview.frame;
```

Hope this will help u. Get the content view of that cell and set frame to it.